# Formatting options in Gmail

Tags: gmail, formatting

I used to be able to see the formatting options (bold, italic, strike-through, etc)
next to the "Send" button, but since some months I can't see it anymore (as in image).

[image]

How can I bring it back ?
I've searched for this on the internet and only seem to find unrelated posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply click on the [image] icon and you will be presented with options shown as follows:

[image]

All of the options generally available within Google Apps are there for selection.

Comment: well.. I could have tried searching a little harder. Thanks !